# Custom view shrinking: previously occupied space is not cleared

Tags: android

In a custom view, OnMeasure and OnSizeChanged is used to set the instrisic size and get the final size respectively.

In OnDraw, a drawable is drawn using the current Width/Height.

Now if the view is told to change its intrisic size, it will requestLayout. This triggers OnMeasure/OnSizeChanged and finally OnDraw.
It works fine, the drawable is always displayed using the correct inner size.

The problem is, if the new inner size is smaller than the old one, android leaves the old drawing (which seems to be "under" the new one, but in fact should have been cleared by android).

I tryed to clear the view content inside OnDraw, but the drawing rectangle is alread clipped to the new view size.

It sounds like a bug in LinearLayout not clearing its content when a child's view size shrink. Testing on Android 4.4 / Samsung S3 4G / CyanogenMod cm-11-20151004-NIGHTLY.

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:padding="8dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:gravity="top">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#CCD39F">
        <MyCustomView
            android:id="@+id/myview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

What i see after updating the custom view size. Only the "black part" should be displayed, not the white one.

[image: What i get]

It should be something like this instead:

[image]

Comment: Could you try it out on a different device? and also could you try replacing `LinearLayout` with some other layout like `RelativeLayout`. Just wanted to  isolate the problem. Also what do you mean by `Only the "black part" should be displayed, not the white one.`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and a workaround.
The real problem is in LinearLayout. From Android 4.0.3 to Android 6. When this vertical linearlayout has weight=1 and height=0dp, and it has only one child which height is smaller than the available height. The first time this child is drawn, no problem. If the height of this child shrink, the area below it is not repainted. So it stays with the old content of the first child, instead of being refilled with the layout background color.

In the following layout code, i demonstrate the problem and solution. The solution is to add a second child which will take the rest of the free space below the first child. Using this technics it works as expected when the first child shrinks, the second one expands and the newly "empty" space is repainted correctly.

So it is really a bug in LinearLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#CCD39F">
            <MyCustomView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Solution. To see the problem, remove the following layout -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#111111" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right">
        <Button
            android:text="Other demo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnNextImage" />
        <Button
            android:text="Next SVG"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnGoEmpty" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```